# Why am I suddenly seeing this instead of normal inventory?

Tags: technical-issues, factorio

I'm running Factorio Demo on Ubuntu,everytime I start the game for quite some time I'm able to run it normally and I'm able to open the inventory tab but after some time I'm getting this protoype screen everytime I open the inventory tab
EDIT: Added a image
[image][image]

Comment: does this happen in all saves or just one?